# Opening a selected folder path in OS X El Capitan 10.11.2?

Tags: macos, keyboard, finder, shortcut

At work we have a file server to share files and in the past I have been able to open the folder path in finder by highlighting the path a coworker provides and then pressing **cmd+option+ctrl+o**. At some point, this shortcut stopped working and it seems like it happened right around the time I updated to El Capitan. Does anyone know if this shortcut has changed or how I can re-enable it if it somehow got disabled?

**Example path:** `/Volumes/clients/someclient/project/`

Comment: there are a lot of ways - but i think the most simple one will be to open press Cmd-DownArrow to open a selected folder (if you mean selected inside of a finder window) - if not finder can you be more clear on where you have selected the path

Comment: The path can be selected anywhere, it could be in a text file, it could be in an email, it could be in a browser address bar. It didn't matter where the path was, I could select the text and then use the above keyboard shortcut and it would automatically open a finder window with that path.

Comment: I tried your Key-Combo on my New Mac (still on Maveriks) and also on my older One which still has Yosemite on it. On Both the Key Combo "cmd+option+ctrl+o" has no Funktion also i have checked it with KeyBindigsEditor same there nothing listed - i think either this Funktion was Removed with Yosemite or earlier or you had installed a Plugin or 3rd Party App which gave you the abillity to do this.

Comment: To get this Function back you can either use a Automator Action Save it as an App and bind it to a HotKey in System Preferences. or if you already have Alfred 2 installed i whould prefer to do it there. (Better Performace) if you need help on this let me know i can help you on that

Answer (score 2):

command shift g when a finder window is open

Comment: I know about that one, the one I'm describing doesn't require a finder window to be open and you don't have to copy and paste the path, you just highlight the path, then use the shortcut and it automatically opens a finder window directly to the path.

Comment: OMG - thank you. I have a Mac for work and Finder drives me nuts - so much harder to see/edit/copy/paste the current path than in Windows. This makes it so much easier (but still not as easy as Windows!)

Answer (score 0):

```
open .
```

Will open the current directory in Finder

**Edit:**
If you're looking for a keyboard shortcut, I'd map whatever key combo you choose to just insert that when typed with a return

Comment: Not what I'm looking for, thanks though.